# BUGS error messages

Tags: r, winbugs, r2winbugs

I am new to WinBUGS/OpenBUGS and having difficulty debugging my code.

Does anyone know of a list of potential error messages for BUGS models and their meanings in plain English?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The WinBUGS [manual](http://www.politicalbubbles.org/bayes_beach/manual14.pdf) has a list of some common error. I have added some additional notes from my own experience:

- **expected variable name** indicates an inappropriate variable name.  I occasionally get this error in providing the data, might have used `1.02e04` instead of `1.02E04`.
- **undefined variable** - variables in a data file must be defined in a model (just put them in as constants or with vague priors). If a logical node is reported undefined, the problem may be with a node on the 'right hand side'. I occasionally get this error when I have removed a variable from the model but not from the data or missed a comma in the data.
- **invalid or unexpected token scanned** - check that the value field of a logical node in a Doodle has been completed.
- **index out of range** - usually indicates that a loop-index goes beyond the size of a vector (or matrix dimension); sometimes, however, appears if the # has been omitted from the beginning of a comment line
- **linear predictor in probit regression too large** indicates numerical overflow. See possible solutions below for Trap 'undefined real result'.
- **logical expression too complex** - a logical node is defined in terms of too many parameters/constants or too many operators: try introducing further logical nodes to represent parts of the overall calculation; for example, a1 + a2 + a3 + b1 + b2 + b3 could be written as A + B where A and B are the simpler logical expressions a1 + a2 + a3 and b1 + b2 + b3, respectively. Note that linear predictors with many terms should be formulated by 'vectorizing' parameters and covariates and by then using the `inprod(.,.)` function
- **unable to choose update method** indicates that a restriction in the program has been violated

You might also hit a trap at the start or during the MCMC. The BUGS manual list the following common traps (I always get the first two, never met the last two):

- **undefined real result** indicates numerical overflow. Possible reasons include:

  - initial values generated from a 'vague' prior distribution may be numerically extreme - specify appropriate initial values;
  - numerically impossible values such as log of a non-positive number - check, for example, that no zero expectations have been given when Poisson modelling;
  - numerical difficulties in sampling. Possible solutions include:
  - better initial values;
  - more informative priors - uniform priors might still be used but with their range restricted to plausible values;
  - better parameterisation to improve orthogonality;
  - standardisation of covariates to have mean 0 and standard deviation 1.
  - can happen if all initial values are equal.Probit models are particularly susceptible to this problem, i.e. generating undefined real results. If a probit is a stochastic node, it may help to put reasonable bounds on its distribution, e.g.

    ```
      probit(p[i]) <- delta[i]
      delta[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau)I(-5, 5)
    ```

    This trap can sometimes be escaped from by simply clicking on the update button. The equivalent construction

    ```
      p[i] <- phi(delta[i])
    ```

    may be more forgiving.
- **index array out of range**
  possible reasons include:

  - attempting to assign values beyond the declared length of an array;
  - if a logical expression is too long to evaluate break it down into smaller components.
- **stack overflow** can occur if there is a recursive definition of a logical node.
- **NIL dereference (read)** can occur at compilation in some circumstances when an inappropriate transformation is made, for example an array into a scalar.
- Trap messages referring to **DFreeARS** indicate numerical problems with the derivative-free adaptive rejection algorithm used for log-concave distributions. One possibility is to change to "Slice" sampling

Answer (score 2):

This [WinBUGS User Manual](http://www.politicalbubbles.org/bayes_beach/manual14.pdf) might be of some use.